# Building an HTML select with dynamic options compatible with iOS Safari select

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I'm building a complicated form with a select that show/hides its options depending on the date chosen in another field:

```
// if a certain date is chosen
$('#shipType1').hide();
$('#shipType2').hide();
$('#shipType3').hide();
```

This works on desktop browsers. However iOS Mobile Safari still displays all 6 of my original options.

On iOS it seems that the select is something custom, native to Mobile Safari, where the initial 'page loaded' options exist and cannot be changed like we can do on desktop browsers.

Is there anyone experienced with manipulating iOS Safari Select options?

Comment: Desktop browsers technically shouldn't allow you to remove `option` elements from a `select` by hiding them either. You should `remove` them instead

Comment: Won't work in IE either. Hiding option tag or trying to bind events to them doesn't work. Best is to filter them and remove, or you can also disable

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan and chalietfl that was absolutely correct.